# Using jersey, is it possible to hide certain class properties?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

Say I have a user class, that has a password property.

When I expose this class in a restful api call using jersey, is it possible to somehow mark the 'password' property so it doesn't get exposed (converted to json or xml)?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried ?

```
 @XmlTransient
```